# Wildfly Undertow: jakarta.servlets.Servlet does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, wildfly, undertow

I am trying to migrate some Servlets from javax libraries to jakarta. Changes are pretty straightforward but, when I try to run them on Wildfly 23, I get this error message:

`Servlet JAX-WS-Service of type class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet`

This happens for this servlet (used for JAXWS, but that's not the point) but also with my own servlets, which look like this:

```
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.Cookie;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet(name = "entrada", loadOnStartup = 1)
public class ServletEntrada extends HttpServlet
```

I'm using Jakarta servlet-api version 5.0.0. The servlets are declared in the `web.xml` file like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletEntrada</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.telventi.framework.web.ServletEntrada</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

If I leave this declaration on `web.xml`, I get the error I mention, `ServletEntrada does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet`.

If I remove this declaration from the `web.xml` file, the servlet is not deployed. Even though, it has the `@WebServlet` annotation, which should make the Servlet automatically discovered by Wildfly.

I guess `undertow` checks for every servlet declared in `web.xml` file if they extend `javax.servlet.Servlet`, but of course the jakarta `HttpServlet` extends `jakarta.servlets.Servlet`, not `javax.servlets.Servlet`.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use WildFly Preview for JakartaEE 9 support, the default WildFly distribution is still Java EE / Jakarta EE 8

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the same issue I had with Web Services, didn't realize there was a connection. I'll try and let you know if it works! Thanks!